# Magenton 1 - If i try to void the order return error - Void Failed: Authorization Not Found (Payeezy)

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, voiding

I am using Payeezy Payment gateway [First Data] If I try to void in back-end order section, I am getting error message **Void Failed: Authorization Not Found**  How can I solve the issue and void the order?

Comment: Do you have a link to the extension you are using also any error logs which will make this easier to answer

Comment: There is no error log generated